# Python Refactoring - Changing Variable Type and Value Within a Loop

Tags: python, refactoring

I'm working on automating some word and PDF documents that need to be updated on a certain cadence.
The way I'm doing this is using dictionaries that replace variables within word documents.

My code works but because my area is not tech savvy I'm using an excel file so people can replace the values in that file whenever they need to update the documents.

I was also successful on pulling the dictionary key and values from excel but I'm trying to refactor this code which is repetitive. Here is an excerpt with 2 of the 7 dictionaries I'm creating:

```
dic = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',"AD")
AD = dict(zip(dic.Key,dic.Value))

dic = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',"RSM")
RSM = dict(zip(dic.Key,dic.Value))
```

I'm trying to refactor this so I can run it all within a single loop and trying something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
AD = "AD"
RSM = "RSM"

groups = [AD, RSM]

for item in groups:
    dic = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',item)
    item = dict(zip(dic.Key,dic.Value))
```

So I'm basically first using the variable as a string to call the excel tab within the read_excel method and then I want to replace that same variable to become the output dictionary.

When I print item within the loop I do get the correct dictionaries but I'm not able to output a variable that stores each dictionary that the loop creates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, you can just have a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd

groups = ['AD', 'RSM']

dicts = {}
for item in groups:
    dic = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', item)
    dicts[item] = dict(zip(dic.Key, dic.Value))
```

Now you can just access them like this:

```
print(dicts['AD']['some key'])
```

The values of a dictionary can be anything, including other dictionaries. Keys of dictionaries can be many things as well, as long as they're hashable, and strings are a common choice of course - and the names of your groups are just that.

Also note that I removed the variables named `AD` and `RSM`. You don't really achieve anything by having variables that are named after the string value they are assigned. It only serves to be able to leave off the quotes where you use the values, but it creates an additional indirection that serves no purpose.

If you don't even need the list of groups, but just want `groups` to be the actual dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd

groups = {}
for item in ['AD', 'RSM']:
    dic = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', item)
    groups[item] = dict(zip(dic.Key, dic.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign the result to the `item` variable and not to an entry in the list.

A simple fix would be to use a dictionary instead of a list to save the reult, eg

```py
import pandas as pd
AD = "AD"
RSM = "RSM"

groups = {AD: None, RSM: None}

for item in groups.keys():
    dic = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',item)
    groups[item] = dict(zip(dic.Key,dic.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use an overall dictionary to track your work and also to save the results there. I refactored your code slightly to this:

```
import pandas as pd

groups = dict.fromkeys(('AD', 'RSM'))  # setup main dict containing dicts

for item in groups:
    dic = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', item)
    groups[item] = dict(zip(dic.Key, dic.Value))  # store individual dict
```

There's no need for your global constants that are used only once, so I removed those. I also added some spaces to help your Python code conform with [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), the global standard style guide.
Now you can access each dictionary as you like, for example, `groups['AD']`.